# Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'.Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, next.js, form-data

When I run the code, I have this js Error. I want to save the values of the form in data.

**Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'.**

I use formData in this code

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target);
    var data = new FormData(e.target);
```

And render code like this

```
<form className='signup-form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            <div className='form-group'>
                                <label>{translations[language]['g29']}*</label>
                                <input
                                    type='text'
                                    className='form-control'
                                    placeholder={translations[language]['g91']}
                                    id='name'
                                    required={true}
                                    name='name'
                                    data-error='Please enter your name'
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className='form-group'>
                                <label>{translations[language]['g61']}*</label>
                                <input
                                    type='text'
                                    className='form-control'
                                    placeholder={translations[language]['g92']}
                                    id='surname'
                                    required={true}
                                    name='surname'
                                    data-error='Please enter your Surname'
                                />
                            </div>

                            <div className='form-group'>
                                <label>{translations[language]['g24']}*</label>
                                <input
                                    type='email'
                                    className='form-control'
                                    placeholder={translations[language]['g42']}
                                    id='email'
                                    required={true}
                                    name='email'
                                />
                            </div>

                            <div className='form-group'>
                                <label>{translations[language]['g43']}*</label>
                                <input
                                    type='password'
                                    className='form-control'
                                    placeholder={translations[language]['g44']}
                                    id='password'
                                    required={true}
                                    name='password'
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className='form-group'>
                                <label>{translations[language]['g43']}*</label>
                                <input
                                    type='password'
                                    className='form-control'
                                    placeholder={translations[language]['g93']}
                                    id='passwordControl'
                                    required={true}
                                    name='passwordControl'
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className='form-group'>
                                <label>{translations[language]['g94']}</label>
                                <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
                                    <div style={{ marginRight: '8px', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                        <input
                                            type='radio'
                                            style={{ marginRight: 6 }}
                                            //className={styles.check_input}
                                            name='gender'
                                            id="female"
                                            required={true}
                                        />
                                        <div>{translations[language]['g95']}</div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div style={{ marginRight: '8px', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                        <input
                                            type='radio'
                                            style={{ marginRight: 6 }}
                                            // value={!gender}
                                            //className={styles.check_input}
                                            name='gender'
                                            id="male"
                                            required={true}
                                        />
                                        <div>{translations[language]['g96']}</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                        <input
                                            type='radio'
                                            style={{ marginRight: 6 }}
                                            // value={!gender}
                                            //className={styles.check_input}
                                            name='gender'
                                            id="other"
                                            required={true}
                                        />
                                        <div>{translations[language]['g97']}</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                           
         
              <button onClick={handleSubmit} type='submit' className='btn btn-primary'>
                {translations[language]['g53']}
              </button>
              <Link href='/'>
                <a className='return-store'>{translations[language]['g51']}</a>
              </Link>
            </form>
```

I get an error when I press the sign-up button and I can't find out why.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the error, the parameter must be an instance of `HTMLFormElement`. A simple way to get the form instance in React is to use `useRef`.

```js
import{ useRef } from 'react';

const Form = () => {
  const formRef = useRef(null);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const form = formRef.current;
    if(!form) return false;
    const formData = new FormData(form); 
    console.log(formData);
  }

  return (
    <form ref={formRef} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="text" name="name" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```